# Why Ebay Trading Api keeps on giving empty results?

Tags: php, web-services, api, ebay-api

I have made a call using Trading api GetOrders method and in return get following response;

Input: ReturnAll2017-01-31T23:00:002017-02-20T11:03:00SellerActive**

**Response**:

2017-02-20T11:18:24.932Z Success 1001 **

```
<TotalNumberOfPages>0</TotalNumberOfPages>
<TotalNumberOfEntries>0</TotalNumberOfEntries>
```

I have also used GetTransactions, GetItemTransactions method but same response appears. However we have transactions in above dates!

Documentation Link: http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/index.html

Anyone please suggest!

Comment: It would help if you could post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input: **ReturnAll2017-01-31T23:00:002017-02-20T11:03:00SellerActive**

Based on your input it's look like you are requesting for Active Orders.

As per eBay Document **Active indicates that the cart is active. The 'Active' state is the only order state in which order line items can still be added, removed, or updated in the cart.**

eBay will not return any value because no one order is in active state.

You should try **All,Completed** state.

You can check following link for different eBay order status code.

http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/types/OrderStatusCodeType.html

Comment: Thanks for you response, actually i fixed by login with ebay login credentials via script and call reporting url https://publisher.ebaypartnernetwork.com/PublisherReportsTx which will download CSV of data.

Comment: Is there any document available for that?

Comment: Hi, no there is no document for that, there is a reporting url in csv format that you will find in reporting section. Only thing required is to login via script and just call reporting url then you can find desired results.